# $\sup$ of integrals with unknown function. (norm of linear operators)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

So, lately, I'm struggling with functional analysis exercises like this one:

My linear operator is defined in $L^2 (\mathbb R)$:

$$T : T f = \cos xf(x)+\sin xf(\pi−x).$$

it asks me to find $\|L\|$.

One way to solve it is to consider the functions in there are trigonometric ones and this will make everything much more trivial but my question is about a method where you effectively try to maximize f(x) by building up some sort of Dirac's delta where the other functions naturally maximize themselves, (in this case $\sin^2x$ and $\cos^2x$) which seems I did not understand correctly how to apply.

My idea is to let $f_n := \begin{cases} n & \text{if } (n\pi-\frac{1}{n}) < x < (n\pi+\frac{1}{n}) \\ 0 & \text{if not.} \end{cases} $

then i can integrate over the nonnull domain $[n\pi-\frac{1}{n}, n\pi+\frac{1}{n}]$

and applying the def of $\|T\|_2$ i will get $\|T\|= \frac{g(n)}{\|f\|}$ where $\|f\|=1$ and some sort of function $g(n)$ which I'm asked to find the sup of. Sadly in this case what i get is $\sup \{2n^2/n\}.$

I got the $n^2$ from my choice of $f(x)$ being${}= n$ in the nonnull domain (it's $L^2$ so i need to integrate the square of $f(x)$) and the $1/n$ by choosing $1/n$ as my, let's say, "moving boundary" of my integration domain.

So here it comes the problem, this method is clearly misunderstood by me because the result is a function of my $f(x)$ and in this case, the $g(n)$ is not even limited, if i will chose $f_n=\sqrt n$ in the non null domain, for example, i should have found $\|T\|=1$ (wich is the right answer btw). So, my question is: how that method truly works and, if it does, when?

Comment: you mean $f_n:=...$ instead of $f$ and where is $g$ defined?

Comment: Absolutely. That's a sequence of functions, gonna fix.

Comment: again, what is $g$?

Comment: @crystal_math $2n^2 / n$ is the result of the square integration of the whole $T(f_n)$

Answer (score 2):

With $f \in L^2(R)$, you have $(Tf)(x) := f(x)\cos x + f(\pi - x)\sin x$.
The squared $L^2$ norm of $Tf$ is
\begin{equation}
\vert Tf \vert^2 = \int_R (f(x)\cos x + f(\pi - x)\sin x)^2\, dx.
\end{equation}
Multiply out the integrand to get
\begin{equation*}
\vert Tf \vert^2 = 
\int_R f^2(x)\cos^2 x\, dx
+ 2\int_R f(x) f(\pi - x) \cos x \sin x dx
+ \int_R f^2(\pi - x)\sin^2 x\, dx.
\end{equation*}
The first and third integrals can be combined if you make a change of variable in the third, yielding $\int_R f^2(x)(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x) dx$, which is $\vert f\vert^2$. Now figure out the simple change of variable in the second integral that produces an integrand which is an odd function about the shifted origin, and you can do that integral in your head.

You end up with $\vert Tf \vert^2 = \vert f \vert^2$.

Comment: That's true and correct by my side but id like to find, if possible a solution using sequences of functions to better 
 understand  how that method works.